# How to add 1 day in Date using XSLT

Tags: 2013, xslt

I have a scenario like fetching data from rss feed.every thing is working fine except date field,the date value is not displaying properly(showing 1 day back). How can I achieve this using XSLT 1.0. 
the below peace of code am using

```
<xsl:value-of select="ddwrt:FormatDateTime(string(pubDate),1033,'MM/dd/yyyy')"/>
```

how to add 1 day to above line of code.

Comment: You can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23566734/date-operations-on-xsl-1-0

Answer (score 1):

In XSLT 2.0, `xs:date(pubDate) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')`

If you're stuck with XSLT 1.0, find out if your processor supports the EXSLT dates+times library module.

If not, you'll probably have to resort to calling out to host language extension functions.